# setting a function to be continuous and differentiable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(x)= \frac{x^3}{x}-9x$ when $x<10$ and $\frac{1}{x+a}$ when $x\geq 10$
>   for which a the function is continuous, is it differentiable at this point?

All the I need to do is to find the value of $\frac{x^3}{x}-9x$ at x=10 and to set the same value for $\frac{1}{x+a}$ so there will not be a discontinuity point so I got $a=-\frac{7297}{730}$

Then I need to check that $$lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x+h-\frac{7297}{730}}-\frac{1}{x-\frac{7297}{730}}}{h}=C$$

So I get to $$lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xh-\frac{7297h}{730}-xh-h^2+\frac{7297h}{730}}{(xh+h^2-\frac{7297h}{730})(xh-\frac{7297h}{730})}$$

it is $\frac{0}{0}$ can I use l'hopital  and derive according to $h$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make the function continuous at $x=10$, we need to set up the equation $$\frac{x^3}x-9x=\frac{1}{x+a}\quad\text{for $x$=10} \\ \text{Hence, }10=\frac{1}{a+10} \\ a=-9.9$$To check whether a function is differentiable at a point, one needs to see if the left-hand and right-hand derivatives equal.
The function on LHS is $f(x)=x^2-9x$ so the left derivative is$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^-}\frac{(x+h)^2-9(x+h)-(x^2-9x)}h|_{x=10} \\ =\lim\limits_{h\to 0^-}\frac{(10+h)^2-9(10+h)-10}h \\ =\lim\limits_{h\to 0^-}\frac{h^2+11h}h \\=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^-}(h+11) = 11$$On the other hand, the function on RHS is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-9.9}$. So the right derivative is$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x+h-9.9}-\frac{1}{x-9.9}}{h}|_{x=10}\\= \lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{0.1+h}-10}{h}\\=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1-10(0.1+h)}{h(0.1+h)}\\=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{-10h}{h(0.1+h)} \\ =\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{-10}{0.1+h}\\=-\frac{10}{0.1}=-100$$Since the left derivative and right derivative differ, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=10$.
In your answer, if you've substituted $x=10$ in the first place, the simplification of the limit will be easier to proceed. So in fact, L'Hospital rule is not necessary in this case.